# Change user text field input each stroke and also get changed message

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to format user input into a text field as he (or she) types.  For example, when entering letters into a "state" field in an address, I want to limit the input to two capital letters...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *afterInput = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *letters = [[afterInput componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    textField.text = [[letters substringToIndex:MIN(2, letters.length)] uppercaseString];
    return NO;
}
```

I've found that I need to return `NO`, otherwise I'll get the original input added to my formatted change.

This succeeds in formatting while the user types, but I also need to tell a delegate about every change to the text field.  For this, I added (thanks to SO) this line during init:

```
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Here's the problem:  `textFieldDidChange` gets called on each change, but only when I answer `YES` to `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.  I need to be able to answer NO (so I can format during typing) but still get the changed message.

1) How should I do that? 2) Am I making some bigger mistake, is there a better way to format as we go and get all the right messages from the text field?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach...

Instead of implementing a handler for `UIControlEventEditingChanged`, process the input (pretty much as you already were doing) and then call your own "text changed" method but **only** if the text actually changed:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // get the current text
    NSString *origText = textField.text;

    // "apply" the user's input
    NSString *afterInput = [origText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // filter non-Alpha
    NSString *letters = [[afterInput componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // upper-case the result
    NSString *uString = [[letters substringToIndex:MIN(2, letters.length)] uppercaseString];

    // if the resulting upper-cased string is NOT the same as what was there to begin with...
    if (![origText isEqualToString:uString]) {
        // update the text in the text field
        textField.text = uString;
        // call your own "text changed" method
        [self myTextChangedMethod:textField];
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)myTextChangedMethod:(UITextField *)tf {
    // do what you want here...
    NSLog(@"%@", tf.text);
}
```

Comment: I used much of this idea.  Thanks!